# How does SearchCursors sort records?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, cursor, sorting

How do [ArcPy SearchCursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/SearchCursor/018v00000050000000/) sort records if there is no 'sort_field' specified?

It seems, on the surface, to sort ascending by the primary key. However, I don't want to base my script around this idea, and then after 6 months of using it find out that its not true for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No sorting is applied, meaning they come back in the order that the DBMS returns. You'll see records in sequential order in shapefiles whereas you'll see them in an order determined by the internal rules of how they're stored in other databases such as SQL Server or Oracle. It's best practice to assume 'random order' if no sort column is specified as the order returned will be data source specific and can even vary from query to query *on the same data source*.